# Convert images to numpy array with RGB values

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I have written following code to read set of images in a directory and convert it into NumPy array.

```
    import PIL
    import torch
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import PIL.Image
    
    # Directory containing the images
    image_dir = "dir1/"
    
    # Read and preprocess images
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
        # Check if the file is an image
        if not (filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpg")):
            continue
    
        # Read and resize the image
        filepath = os.path.join(image_dir, filename)
        image = PIL.Image.open(file path)
        image = image.resize((32, 32))  # resize images to (32, 32)
        #print(f"Image shape: {image.shape}")
        # Convert images to NumPy arrays
        image = np.array(image)
        images.append(image)
    
    # Convert images to PyTorch tensors 
    images1 = torch.tensor(np.array(images))
    np.save('trial1.npy', np.array(images),allow_pickle=True)
```

The above code leads to a dataframe of shape `(24312, 32, 32)`. How to convert it into shape `(24312, 32, 32,3)`so that it stores RGB values also as 3 channel ?

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem but all my arrays do have another dimension for the channels. I used an RGB image for that. That leads to the question, are your images grayscale? If not, is `image` already of the wrong shape?

Comment: to convert grayscale to color, use PIL's conversion method

Comment: Also consider `cv2.imread`. OpenCV natively stores images as numpy `ndarray`

Comment: first check your image if its 3 channel, if not you can use the convert function to make it RGB, secondly i dont recommend saving such a huge npy file, save it into smaller files

Comment: Just converted it from grayscale to RBG, and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Edwin Cheong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7617767/edwin-cheong) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74793690/convert-images-to-numpy-array-with-rgb-values#comment132010514_74793690), first check your image if its 3 channel, if not you can use the convert function to make it RGB.